# What is a good warm-up for the trumpet/cornet?

Tags: practice, trumpet

I've been playing the cornet for about a year now. I have found that I can play for about five minutes and then I can't play anymore. When I come back five minutes later, I can play just fine and I play for half an hour to an  hour. I usually just play [Stars and Stripes Forever](http://erato.uvt.nl/files/imglnks/usimg/2/2a/IMSLP27139-PMLP03235-Sousa-StarsStripesPTSBd.pdf) to warm up (the Solo Bb Cornet part, about half way through). I hit the high Bb in the last strain and crawl a few more bars and I'm wiped out. When I come back five minutes later, I can play it as much as I want and I'm fine.

I've also noticed, when I try higher pieces for warm-up, such as the Stars and Stripes Forever as I mentioned, I have trouble with the low notes for the remainder of the practice. However, I'm fine with the high notes. If I try a piece with a lower range, e.g The Thunderer, I can't hit the high notes for the better part of my practice, but I can hit the low notes just fine.

I was wondering if anyone knew of a good warm-up technique. Currently, the high Bb flat is my limit as far as range on a good day.

EDIT:
What other things should I work on during it? I'm looking for specifics. What scales should I work on? How far should I press my range? Should I take breaks during it? etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best warm-up for extending range is likely going to be a series of gently-climbing scales that reach a semitone or two above your highest intended high note.

Disclaimer: I speak strictly from vocal experience.  I couldn't buy an embouchure with my life savings.

This file has what appears to be [every scale ever](http://www.trumpetstudio.com/scales/warmup.pdf).

Comment: And if it's been a while since you started playing, or you're just starting to play, here's some [standard scales](http://cl.ly/2k3i0k0x3f012h071714) you can do too.

Comment: I've been using the Ken Saul warm-ups as well, seem to be pretty good. Generally, trumpet players will not need to reach a semitone or two above the highest intended high note though. More often, the suggested warm up (as outlined in the Ken Saul PDF) is to do long, low tones. See [Wynton Marsalis' practice routine](http://abel.hive.no/trumpet/practice/WM_practice.html).

Answer (score 1):

I usually warm up with about ten minutes of scales, arpeggios, diminished sevenths and so on - they should be fairly gentle and start off very easy. If you want a slightly quicker version, you could try crabwise scales (go up the scale in C, come down in C#, go up again in D and so on).

You could also play a simple piece (or one you know really well but isn't too high) and transpose into a different key - the point being that you don't want to do anything too strenuous before your lips are warmed up properly. By the end of the warm-up (if you're doing scales), you should be covering pretty much your entire range.

Answer (score 0):

I excellently warm up with trumpet using the [Charles Colin Advanced Lip Flexibilities Complete for Trumpet](http://www.samash.com/p/Charles%20Colin_Advanced%20Lip%20Flexibilities%20Complete%20for%20Trumpet_-49974493)
I practice the first excerices, that are basically harmonics or triads.

My best warming up is as follow:

- breath 10 times as deeper as I can
- 2-4 minutes of excercises only with mouthpiece
- 2.4 minutes of exercises with the trumpet

it works.

After 3 months of playing I can cover 2 full octaves.

Answer (score 0):

I usually start with the Caruso " lip, mouthpiece, instrument routine" ( buzz G inthe staff for a count of 5, rest for 5, then G flat and so on down to C then do the same on the mouthpiece and finally on the instrument). I follow that with some "Stamp" warmups